# Soundcloud HTML5 widget can't be used with Xenforo

Tags: embed, soundcloud

When trying to get the Soundcloud HTML5 widget to embed in a Xenforo forum I notice that it requires the Track ID which is not availiable in the URL of the page. Is there a way to get the track id without having to scrape the source code or force the user to get it from the whole embed code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/resolve` endpoint: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

```
$ curl -v 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID'

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Location: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json
```

See for yourself: [http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic](http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID)